# Calculating adjusted odds ratios in a multiple logistic regression model (adjusted for more than one predictors)

Tags: r, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I want to calculate an adjusted odds ratio, adjusted for three predictors, of a multiple logistic regression. However, I do not know how to calculate one adjusted odds ratio, that is adjusting for set, age and mv.
Here is an example of running the multiple logistic regression in R:

```
glm(formula = early_stop ~ set + age + 
    mv, family = "binomial", data = DAT1)

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3

**coefficients(model_output)**

(Intercept):                     
1.979493e+00
exp = 7.239072

set:
-7.687910e-01
exp = 0.4635732

age: 
-5.670446e-05
exp = 0.9999433 

mv: 
1.019634e-01
exp = 1.107343
```

Is there a way to calculate one adjusted odds ratio for early_stop that is adjusting for these three predictors?

Comment: What exactly should the odds ratio refer to? Overall odds? Pairwise odds? Weighted odds? Have you researched contrast coding or the emmeans package?

Comment: The adjusted odds ratio should refer to early_stop, taking into account set, age and mv.

Comment: Does this help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/565816/interpret-ratio-odds-in-a-binomial-logistic-regression-model-to-demonstrate-effe

Comment: Sorry for late answer but this helps a lot, thankyou!

Comment: Glad to hear it.